# Get Lat/Long corresponding to overlay marker in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps on Android, and I have a marker as an overlay in my MapView. My question is, how do I get the latitude/longitude corresponding to the position of my marker on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added a class-level variable and used it to keep track of the marker position as it changed, and queried that when I wanted the value. If someone has a better answer, please post it; otherwise I'm assuming this is the best way to go.